# Problem with query based on timestamp and Instant

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, timezone

I trying to make the query in criteria api and I looking for rows where the date is greater or equal as provided.

Database Oracle -> hibernate -> spring boot application

Oracle column definition: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Hibernate configuraton:  jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC

Server and database are in a different timezone.

Column map as Instant

```java
    criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), this.startDate)
```

Generated sql:

```
entity0_.date>=? 

BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2019-10-01T00:11:11Z]
```

When I do this query in sqlplus

```
select * from plan where date >= TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 00:11:11 UTC'
```

I got the correct result but in hibernate, I got additional row where the date is eg. 2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC' which is incorrect behavior.

Any idea what is wrong with this code?

Ps. For ZonedDateTime it's the same behavior

Comment: At a guess, it appears to be casting the timestamp to a date in Java, which would remove the time component and then casting back to a timestamp which would result in the time component being set to midnight.

Comment: Another possible explanation is a time zone issue. Would it include a result from just before midnight too?

Comment: I found one way to solve it but it's not pretty and I don't know why properties did not cover it:
-Duser.timezone=UTC

Comment: Great! You may post that as an answer to your own question.